# Añadir botón de localización Google Maps en mi aplicación (Android Java)

Tags: java, android

A ver estaba buscando como añadir el botón de detectar mi posición. He conseguido añadirlo solicitando el permiso de ubicación, pero me surge otro problema, y es que cuando le doy el permiso, tengo que salir y volver a entrar a la aplicación para que me aparezca bien todo, dejo el código:

```
package com.isaac.appet;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class FinderFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.finder_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    1);
            return;
        }

            mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
            mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        LatLng sevilla = new LatLng(37.3886303, -5.9953403);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sevilla).draggable(true).title("Sevilla").snippet("Este es el marcador de Sevilla").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mapicon)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sevilla, 15));
    }



}
```

Si necesitáis algún otro archivo de código para poder verlo decidmelo y edito con el código para facilitaros lo más posible resolver mi problema, que al final resultará una tontería, pero no doy con ello...

Comment: Pero no estas obteniendo tu ubicacion lo que estas haciendo es ubicar tu marker en "sevilla"

Comment: En este punto quería solamente poder mostrar el botón de mostrar la ubicación pero claro, si que me gustaría que cada vez que abro el mapa me mande a mí ubicación, pero no sé cómo guardar mi ubicación para poder pasársela a un LatLng y que me mande allí, o si hay otra forma de hacerlo...